# Scrollable html <div> that has overflow on top

Tags: html, tooltip, overflow, scrollable

I have a div that has the overflow property set to scroll. In this div I have smaller divs, that show a tooltip when someone hovers over them. My problem is that the tooltips of the divs at the top get cut off and you don´t see them.
Is there any way to display overflow on the top, but have the div remain scrollable?

Comment: Can you do `position:absolute` for the tool tips?

Comment: It is, but it doesn´t change anything

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to prevent everything from overflowing besides certain elements. However, if you're able to position the tooltips outside of the scrollable div, you could try something like this:

```css
div.outer {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 30px auto;
 }
 
 div.inner {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: lightgrey;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
 }
 
 .tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index: 1;
 }
 
 .inner:hover .tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <span class="tooltip">Text 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <span class="tooltip">Text 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <span class="tooltip">Text 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```